# YouTube API Not Posting Comments Properly

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm testing the youtube API with the example code they have given on their website and trying to post a reply to a thread.

Everything works fine and when I visit the page I see my comment there, except it's not there.

Only I can see the comment, if I login from another account or just open youtube in incognito window it doesn't show up.

On the other hand, if I manually post the comment myself it shows up everywhere, but I want to be able to do it through the API.

Any fix? Thanks.

Comment: Same here, code gets executed but not reflecting comments on video

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to insert/post your comment on the YouTube Video. The [`Comments: insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) and [`CommentThreads: insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert).

The **Comments: insert** is used when replying to an existing comment.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "snippet": {
  "textOriginal": "YOUR_COMMENT",
  "parentId": "The unique ID of the parent comment"
 }
}
```

Now, for the new comment, use the **CommentThreads: insert** to create a new top-level comment.

Here is the request that you need to use.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "snippet": {
  "channelId": "channel Id of the video",
  "topLevelComment": {
   "snippet": {
    "textOriginal": "YOUR_COMMENTS",
    "videoId": "the Id of the video"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

If you only know the `videoId` and not the `channelId` of the video in where you want to comment, you can use the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get the channelId by only using the videoId.

> NOTE: When checking the comments that you post by using the API, you
>   need to click and select **Newest first** to view the latest comments.

[image]